# Shutdown monitor on debian server

Tags: linux, debian, monitor, shutdown

I'm running a debian server and because the pc is in my room and always running I want to shutdown the monitor.

I have no graphic interface so

```
xset dpms force off
```

doesn't work (returning: xset:  unable to open display "")

I try "setterm powerdown" commands but it only "clear" the screen but it still produces light (black screen but with background light ... )

So after major google research I'm comming here.
The cool thing will be shutdown monitor after inactivity and power on if a keyboard keys is pressed.

Only poweroff the screen will be fine because I'm using ssh to manage the server.

Comment: If it is in your room, can you not just press the power off button?

Comment: It's a server, I do not want to shut it down or put it in hibernate mode.
(And by the way I broke the power button a month ago, this is why it's became my @home server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on linux commands but i remember that it is similiar to something "xset -display :0 dpms force off". You can try this one.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I went into:

```
 /sys/class/backlight/gmux_backlight
```

then

```
 sudo nano brightness
```

and change it to 0

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use vbetool (only on amd64 or i386). It requires root access, so run it from root or use sudo.

Switch monitor off:
vbetool dpms off

Turn it on again (keyboard don't do it):
vbetool dpms on

Comment: If you get "Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface)" then you need to do this first: "mount -o remount,exec /dev" (and afterwards: "mount -o remount,noexec /dev") -- all as root.

Answer (score 0):

Kupson: I didn't test vbetool. But I think it's a correct answer from what I see about vbetool.
Emreakyilmaz: 
    xset dpms force off
or
    xset -display :0 dpms force off
both don't work.

I solved it by disable the hibernate function when I close the laptop. So the screen turn off, but the pc still running.